# How to fetch token when it is generating by JS for sending requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am creating a script for this site:

The first section (making the account is done):
https://my.shaadi.com/profile-creation/step/1?gtrk=1

However when configuring profiles I am having an issue, the page is loaded by JS and the token is generated using JS as well.

https://my.shaadi.com/static/js/main.4c82cc30.js
this is the JS file:

```
X-Access-Token: 2a719ecb4cf7a3ef45676834a596bc58|4SH80109362|
X-App-Key: 69c3f1c1ea31d60aa5516a439bb65949cf3f8a1330679fa7ff91fc9a5681b564
```

These are the 2 tokens I am looking to get
I can't figure out a way of getting these is it possible to use requests to do this or would it require a headless browser to run the JS (I am wanting to do it in pure python requests)

Answer (score 0):

The best/easiest is use selenium or dryscrape  and BeautifulSoup.

```
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

client = webdriver.PhantomJS()
#client.get('https://my.shaadi.com/profile-creation/step/1?gtrk=1')
client.get('https://my.shaadi.com/static/js/main.4c82cc30.js')
body = client.page_source
```

Now you can parse body with regexp or BeautifulSoup

Comment: is there no way to do this using pure requests, I saw that if there is an api call then that could be replicated using requests, however I can't see any outgoing requests in which I could replicate

Comment: when running the code you have provided , it simply returns the text that I would receive by doing session.get(url) , it doesn't seem to have executed the JS and provided the accesstoken

Comment: @John You must probably login with selenium and then get the access token, https://www.thetaranights.com/login-to-a-website-using-selenium-python-python-selenium-example/